# Cakephp cannot find my tag.ctp file

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

After I have installed a XAMPP Server, I wanted to install cakephp on my server. So far everything works fine. I have generated the scaffold code explained in the beginner tutorial that is on the cakephp tutorial

However, it is time for me to retrieve bookmarks with a Specific Tag and I am following the codes, step by step, but it is not displaying the tag when I try to call it by its URL. It keeps telling me the template is missing. It says the tags .ctp file has not been created.

This is irritating me, because I have been going through the codes over and over to see if I missed something, but nothing. Thank you.

This is the code for the BookmarkController

```
use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Bookmarks Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\BookmarksTable $Bookmarks
 */
class BookmarksController extends AppController
{
    public function tags()
    {
        // The 'pass' key is provided by CakePHP and contains all
        // the passed URL path segments in the request.
        $tags = $this->request->params['pass'];

        // Use the BookmarksTable to find tagged bookmarks.
        $bookmarks = $this->Bookmarks->find('tagged', [
            'tags' => $tags
        ]);

        // Pass variables into the view template context.
        $this->set([
            'bookmarks' => $bookmarks,
            'tags' => $tags
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Users']
        ];
        $this->set('bookmarks', $this->paginate($this->Bookmarks));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmarks']);
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Bookmark id.
     * @return void
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Users', 'Tags']
        ]);
        $this->set('bookmark', $bookmark);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmark']);
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->patchEntity($bookmark, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Bookmarks->save($bookmark)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The bookmark has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The bookmark could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $users = $this->Bookmarks->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $tags = $this->Bookmarks->Tags->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('bookmark', 'users', 'tags'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmark']);
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Bookmark id.
     * @return void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Tags']
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->patchEntity($bookmark, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Bookmarks->save($bookmark)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The bookmark has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The bookmark could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $users = $this->Bookmarks->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $tags = $this->Bookmarks->Tags->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('bookmark', 'users', 'tags'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmark']);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Bookmark id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->get($id);
        if ($this->Bookmarks->delete($bookmark)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The bookmark has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The bookmark could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

This is the BookMarkerTable code

```
use App\Model\Entity\Bookmark;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Bookmarks Model
 *
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Users
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany $Tags
 */



class BookmarksTable extends Table
{

// The $query argument is a query builder instance.
// The $options array will contain the 'tags' option we passed
// to find('tagged') in our controller action.
public function findTagged(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $this->find()
        ->distinct(['Bookmarks.id'])
        ->matching('Tags', function ($q) use ($options) {
            if (empty($options['tags'])) {
                return $q->where(['Tags.title IS' => null]);
            }
            return $q->where(['Tags.title IN' => $options['tags']]);
        });
}
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */

// The $query argument is a query builder instance.
// The $options array will contain the 'tags' option we passed
// to find('tagged') in our controller action.

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('bookmarks');
        $this->displayField('title');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Tags', [
            'foreignKey' => 'bookmark_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'joinTable' => 'bookmarks_tags'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('title');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('description');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('url');

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['user_id'], 'Users'));
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Below is the content of the file.txt that contains the src folder

```
 C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Console
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Controller
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\files.txt
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Shell
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\View
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Console\Installer.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Controller\AppController.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Controller\BookmarksController.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Controller\Component
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Controller\PagesController.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Controller\TagsController.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Controller\UsersController.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Controller\Component\empty
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model\Behavior
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model\Entity
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model\Table
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model\Behavior\empty
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model\Entity\Bookmark.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model\Entity\Tag.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model\Entity\User.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model\Table\BookmarksTable.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model\Table\TagsTable.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Model\Table\UsersTable.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Shell\ConsoleShell.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Bookmarks
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Element
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Email
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Error
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Pages
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Tags
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Users
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Bookmarks\add.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Bookmarks\edit.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Bookmarks\index.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Bookmarks\tags.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Bookmarks\view.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Element\Flash
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Element\Flash\default.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Element\Flash\error.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Element\Flash\success.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Email\html
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Email\text
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Email\html\default.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Email\text\default.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Error\error400.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Error\error500.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout\ajax.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout\default.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout\Email
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout\error.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout\rss
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout\Email\html
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout\Email\text
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout\Email\html\default.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout\Email\text\default.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Layout\rss\default.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Pages\home.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Tags\add.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Tags\edit.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Tags\index.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Tags\view.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Users\add.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Users\edit.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Users\index.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\Template\Users\view.ctp
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\View\AjaxView.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\View\AppView.php
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\View\Helper
    C:\Users\Pamela\bookmarkers\src\View\Helper\empty
```

Comment: Do what @InigoFlores asked. Supply us with some meaning code ;)

Comment: I have just the code posted above... thank you

Comment: It says to post the code for the View in the tag.ctp file, but that file has not been created. I presume it creates automatically from the code above which does not work.

Comment: Php version is 5.5.11

Answer (score 1):

I believe you haven't completed the part where the tutorial instructs you to create the file `src/Template/Bookmarks/tags.ctp`.

> Now if you visit the `/bookmarks/tagged` URL, CakePHP will show an error letting you know that you have not made a view file. Next, let’s build the view file for our `tags()` action. In `src/Template/Bookmarks/tags.ctp` put the following content:

```
<h1>
    Bookmarks tagged with
    <?= $this->Text->toList($tags) ?>
</h1>

<section>
    <?php foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark): ?>
        <article>
            <!-- Use the HtmlHelper to create a link -->
            <h4><?= $this->Html->link($bookmark->title, $bookmark->url) ?></h4>
            <small><?= h($bookmark->url) ?></small>

            <!-- Use the TextHelper to format text -->
            <?= $this->Text->autoParagraph($bookmark->description) ?>
        </article>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</section>
```

See [Cookbook 3.x: Bookmark Tutorial: Creating the View](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html#creating-the-view).

Comment: Hi, sorry I have added this, but it still throws up the same error.

Comment: Please provide a full list of your files and folders under ' /src' . To do this, open a `CMD` terminal, chdir to your CakePHP installation folder, and type `dir /s /b src > files.txt`. Edit your question and paste the content of this file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I did, but I just re-did the exercise, copied the code all over again and it worked! Looks like I made a mistake the first time.

Thanks, guys.